# Cocoapods: dependencies for iOS Framework project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

In Cocoapods, what is the right way to manage dependencies for iOS Framework project? Let's say I have a framework A, do I declare dependencies for the framework directly in Cocoapods:

`target 'FrameworkA' do
  workspace 'MyWS'
  project 'FrameworkA/FrameworkA.xcodeproj'
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  pod 'ObjectMapper'
end`

Or should I not do this and only declare the actual pod dependencies in the app target?

Comment: You should follow the documentation for any particular pod

Comment: Maybe this article can help? https://medium.com/swiftindia/build-an-ios-watchos-and-tvos-framework-with-a-dependency-using-cocoapods-80cb9307992f